# Puzzling behavior in scalaz-stream with chunk and zipWithIndex

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7, scalaz-stream

I am trying to process a stream of data using scalaz-stream with an expensive operation※.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

    def expensive[T](x:T): T = {
      println(s"EXPENSIVE! $x")
      x
    }
    ^D
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

expensive: [T](x: T)T
```

※Yes, yes, I know mixing in code with side-effects is bad functional programming style. The print statements are just to track the number of times expensive() gets called.)

Before passing the data to the expensive operation, I first need to split it into chunks.

```
scala> val chunked: Process[Task,Vector[Int]] = Process.range(0,4).chunk(2)
chunked: scalaz.stream.Process[scalaz.concurrent.Task,Vector[Int]] = Await(scalaz.concurrent.Task@7ef516f3,<function1>,Emit(SeqView(...),Halt(scalaz.stream.Process$End$)),Emit(SeqView(...),Halt(scalaz.stream.Process$End$)))

scala> chunked.runLog.run
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Vector[Int]] = Vector(Vector(0, 1), Vector(2, 3), Vector())
```

Then I map the expensive operation onto the stream of chunks.

```
scala> val processed = chunked.map(expensive)
processed: scalaz.stream.Process[scalaz.concurrent.Task,Vector[Int]] = Await(scalaz.concurrent.Task@7ef516f3,<function1>,Emit(SeqViewM(...),Halt(scalaz.stream.Process$End$)),Emit(SeqViewM(...),Halt(scalaz.stream.Process$End$)))
```

When I execute this, it calls expensive() the expected number of times:

```
scala> processed.runLog.run
EXPENSIVE! Vector(0, 1)
EXPENSIVE! Vector(2, 3)
EXPENSIVE! Vector()
res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Vector[Int]] = Vector(Vector(0, 1), Vector(2, 3), Vector())
```

However, if I chain a call to zipWithIndex, expensive() gets called many more times:

```
>scala processed.zipWithIndex.runLog.run
EXPENSIVE! Vector()
EXPENSIVE! Vector()
EXPENSIVE! Vector()
EXPENSIVE! Vector()
EXPENSIVE! Vector(0)
EXPENSIVE! Vector(0)
EXPENSIVE! Vector(0)
EXPENSIVE! Vector(0)
EXPENSIVE! Vector(0, 1)
EXPENSIVE! Vector()
EXPENSIVE! Vector()
EXPENSIVE! Vector()
EXPENSIVE! Vector()
EXPENSIVE! Vector(2)
EXPENSIVE! Vector(2)
EXPENSIVE! Vector(2)
EXPENSIVE! Vector(2)
EXPENSIVE! Vector(2, 3)
EXPENSIVE! Vector()
EXPENSIVE! Vector()
EXPENSIVE! Vector()
EXPENSIVE! Vector()
EXPENSIVE! Vector()
EXPENSIVE! Vector()
res3: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Vector[Int], Int)] = Vector((Vector(0, 1),0), (Vector(2, 3),1), (Vector(),2))
```

Is this a bug? If it is the desired behavior, can anybody explain why? If expensive() takes a long time, you can see why I would prefer the result with fewer calls.

Here is a gist with more examples: https://gist.github.com/underspecified/11279251

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scalaz/BKHWa5hf2Ok/7K5d9crJ088J), which can take a number of [different forms](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scalaz/BKHWa5hf2Ok/7K5d9crJ088J). The problem is essentially that `map` can see (and do stuff with) the intermediate steps that `chunk` is taking while it builds up its results.

This behavior [may change in the future](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scalaz/Li1uWmxSLlM/tOZF5eIDm6UJ), but in the meantime there are a couple of possible workarounds. One of the simplest is to wrap your expensive function in a process and use `flatMap` instead of `map`:

```
chunked.flatMap(a =>
  Process.eval(Task.delay(expensive(a)))
).zipWithIndex.runLog.run
```

Another solution is to wrap your expensive function in an effectful channel:

```
def expensiveChannel[A] = Process.constant((a: A) => Task.delay(expensive(a)))
```

Now you can use `through`:

```
chunked.through(expensiveChannel).zipWithIndex.runLog.run
```

While the current behavior can be a little surprising, it's also a good reminder that you should be using the type system to help you track *all* the effects you care about (and long-running computation can be one of these).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and references. Wrapping my expensive process in a delay got rid of the excess calls. Essentially, the problem is a result of how scala-streams is mixing strict and lazy evaluation, right? What I still don't understand is why chunk's results aren't fully finalized before map is called. Is that impossible with streamed data?